# Regex parsing url() and @imports in CSS

Tags: c#, regex, parsing, url

I'm new in regex and i'm trying to parse the CSS file, to get the:

- @imports "file.css"
- url (pathtoFile)

But it fails.

```
Regex cssUrls = new Regex(@"(url|@import)\((?<char>['""])?(?<url>.*?)\k<char>?\)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        foreach (Match item in cssUrls.Matches(sData))
        {


            MessageBox.Show(item.Groups[2].Value);


        }
```

Anyone can help me please ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
@import ([""'])(?<url>[^""']+)\1|url\(([""']?)(?<url>[^""')]+)\2\)
```